How can I retrieve a Telegram group chat id to send message with a script?
I am developing a script in python to send a crypto monitoring in a Telegram group, but I don't find the "Chat ID" which is necessary for their API so as to send message in a group. Can anyone help me ?
Here is a screenshot of my script :

Link


remove the screenshot and paste the code / error messages as text in your question

You better remove your API KEY from screenshot, this is totally not secure. Anyone can use it

and this is not even a coding question
